# Expected behaviour on page refresh with react router and express?

Tags: express, reactjs, react-router

I am hoping this is a simple question. I have an express server with one route.

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/src/index.html'));
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

The index.html links to the js below:

```js
import React                                   from 'react';
import ReactDOM                                from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import Redux                                   from 'redux';

var App = React.createClass({
  render: () => {
    return(
      <div>React!
        <Link to={`/page2`}>Page 2</Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var AnotherView = React.createClass({
  render: () => {
    return(
      <div>Page 2
      <Link to={`/`}>App</Link></div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}></Route>
    <Route path="/page2" component={AnotherView}/>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

I can click the links and the urls change when I go to localhost:3000 and start from there. The question is this, what should happen if I go to localhost:3000/page2 when using the router? Is it supposed to figure out that its supposed to show the AnotherView component and show it? I am getting "Cannot GET /page2" from express. If it is what do I need to do to make it do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/src/index.html'));
});
```

The server should handle all the request, not only `'/'`.